# Let's change the Photo-SE badge icons to something specific to photography!

Tags: feature-request, design, badges

Some of the Stack Exchange communities have custom badge icons (skeptics is the first one that comes to mind).

I think it would be really neat if we replaced our generic copper, silver, and gold squares with little SLRs or something like that instead. I'll post two ideas that I have.

Just as an FYI our badge colors are:

- copper (e19375)
- silver (b4b4b4)
- gold   (f9c923)

Comment: This is meta...?

Comment: Love this idea!

Comment: Thanks! Coming from you that means a lot!

Comment: How can we get Stack Exchange designer eyes on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Camera pictogram from [open clip art](https://openclipart.org/detail/189336/camera-pictogram):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Could be cleaned up a little bit; the lens looks good large but doesn't scale down so well.

Answer (score 3):

Another option (and one that I have a bias towards) would be little film canisters like so.

Again, you'd need to fill with the proper colors.

[image: template]

Comment: This came from shutter stockstock 65461951 and I just took a a thumbnail and clean it up...a lot.

Comment: Here's my attempt at some icons but it would need some fine tuning to work at small size. http://i.imgur.com/tBG6H6q.png

Comment: That's a funny looking memory card.

Comment: @Octopus It certainly is. It also has a *really* limited capacity. At most, you're lucky to get 40 pictures before you have to get a new one!

Answer (score 3):

How about **APERTURE** as the icon? It could be a cliche, but IMHO, it does fit well.

While there is no denying that photography is an art that is a culmination of many things, the camera, the photographer, the subject, various parts of the camera, its accessories, but the underlying or the foundation of photography is LIGHT. And one object that signifies the importance of light is the aperture. Here is my attempt to create the icon, using the color values from OP's message. Also, if you look closely the leaves of the aperture icon resemble cyclic **P** (the alphabet). This could be further modified.
[image: Photo-SE-Icon]

IMAGE SOURCE: http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/lens-aperture_1115

**Some variants in 32px X 32px**

[image: Fills 32px]
[image: Just lines]
[image: background fills]

Answer (score -1):

Here is a Canon 5D MIII as mock up. It has transparency, so all someone would have to do is dump our colors behind it and scale it.

As a note, I'm indifferent if it is a Canon, Nikon, or whatever, but I do think it should have that SLR "look" (so not mirrorless, rangefinder, P&S, etc).

[image: template]

Comment: Will it be legible at something like 20x20 or 30x30 pixels?

Comment: That is a good question. Just scaling it and painting it, someone would have to redraw the lens, but it has a *rough* shape of a camera. I'd love to see someone else give it a try or a suggestion!

Comment: Here's an open licensed, non-branded vector graphic: https://openclipart.org/detail/6682/dslr-camera

Comment: Or better, simpler: https://openclipart.org/detail/76255/slr-camera