# Site Design Updates are Live!

Tags: discussion, design

A majority of the changes are not visible; these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow. We did make some changes to the link color on the main site and the background color on the meta site as we move away from dark-colored site design because of readability issues and consistency with other Stack Exchange Q&A network sites. We're also making the meta themes more and more consistent from site to site.

- We have updated the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We've updated most of the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We've fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.
- Plus, we've launched the new user profile.

Visually it should "feel" close to the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: Any sense on whether or not this will change the contest photo section?

Comment: JoanneC: It shouldn't. We're going to keep things exactly where they are now.

Comment: Ah, cool. Though it might be good to look at image clipping/scaling for those who submit a larger than desired image. Not to add to the workload. :)

Comment: Looks good. I prefer the Meta look in particular.

Comment: Did you test it in firefox?

Comment: Hey Kurtis, the custom site content got stomped by mistake during a recent photo contest update. Do you guys have a copy of it? My old copy isn't good anymore, the para tag falls out of the div and gets hidden. I tweaked the current header so it looks okay, but it's not quite right.

Comment: Though, having said that, I may have got it pretty close... Looking at the screenshots below, it may be fine.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers it would be nice to have the original custom code template saved so that we could have a "reset" button to restore the original in the event that we manage to mess it up

Comment: I am still having IOTW image placement issues as in the posts below. We originally had some CSS somewhere that positioned that for us...and I don't think that was in the actual template. I suspect that CSS would need to be updated for the image to be positioned correctly.

Answer (score 4):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The site header is seriously broken in my Iceweasel 38.4.0:

[image]

Comment: Also the same broken-ness on FireFox 35.0.1

Comment: Same here with Firefox 39.0, openSuse 13.1

Comment: Iceweasel (Firefox) 38.2.1 shows the same on Debian Wheezy. Photo Meta is OK.

Comment: This appears to have been **fixed now.**

Comment: I can confirm this.

Comment: First time I've had to install iceweasel to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Not to self promote, but has there been any consideration on changing the badge icons, as discussed [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4777)?

Comment: The badge colors are now one of the elements that we try to keep consist on every Stack Exchange network site.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers The request is less about the color of the badges, but the shape of the badge itself.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This seems like really heavy bolding to me:

[image]

Comment: Hmm. looking into it.

Comment: So I am not the only one having trouble to see the questions :-)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I find it very difficult to distinguish between different comments now. The screenshot doesn't show it the best but any semi-extended comment thread is quite hard to read for me now:
[image]

Comment: Will darken the lines between comments a bit.

Comment: Wow, quick response and thank you. It's just my opinion, maybe others disagree :)

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The menu overflows the header area in Firefox 42. This screenshot shows cursor hovering last item:

[image: Overflow]

This is also present in meta.
I don't think it's intentional.

**Update**: (Dec 7th) Overflow is now only by 1px and apparently only on Meta:

[image: Overflow update]

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Firefox 42 (answer updated too).

Comment: Not present in Chrome 46.0.2490.86 m.

Comment: Thanks. Will push a fix soon.

Comment: This should be fixed now.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Are we waiting for the next production build or should this be live right now?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers A 1px offset is still there for Firefox 45 and only in Meta (see the Dec 7th update in my answer). Not a big deal, but I just wanted to check if this was still pending to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image]

Image (which is the max 375px) is overlaying the Photography text.

Also see comments under your original post about the custom content, which is not working

Comment: Looks fine to me. Iceweasel 38.2.1, Debian Wheezy.

Comment: Chrome 47.0.2526.73 for me.  Looking again, it is ok as I resize the browser, but if I maximise the browser it overlaps.  Doesn't happen in Firefox or IE11.

Comment: I tried resizing the browser window in all directions, but it stayed fine for me. Just a data point.

Comment: Turns out I had the zoom set to 90%.  Gets progressively worse if I zoom to 70%, 50%.  Not really a big issue then.